# Don't understand the IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$$x^{'} = 3 x^{\frac23}, \qquad x(0) = 0$$

The answers given are $u(t) = 0$ and $v(t) = t^3$.

I should perhaps mention that it's been a while since I did any mathematics and this was given in class today and we were asked as practice to find more solutions to this IVP. Can anyone perhaps explain why $v(t)$ and $u(t)$ are solutions and how they were found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when $$u(t)=0 \to u'(t)=0 \to 
x=u(t) \to 0=3*(0)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$ and 
$$u(t)=t^3 \to u'(t)=3t^2 \to 
x=u(t) \to 3t^2=3*(t^3)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: I literally have no idea why your looking at $u^{'}(t)$

Comment: So basically im looking for a function that's derivative equals the above equation at the point x(0)=0 ?

Comment: Because you have derivitative of x=3*x^(2/3)

Comment: $x(0)=0 $ is trivial solution of your IVP (initial value problem )

Comment: wouldnt any $t^{n} : n>1 $ and an integer work?